# Representation of $GL_2$ on $K^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

In one of my problems it says the following: Let $K$ be an infinite field. Consider the linear action of $GL_2$ on $K[x,y]$ induced by the natural representation of $GL_2$ on $K^2$.

I don't know what the first part means. I know what $GL_2$ looks like, I also know what $K[x,y]$ looks like. I think "the natural representation of $GL_2$ on $K^2$" means that we look at $GL_2$ as $2x2$ matrices, with entries in $K$, and let that act in the natural way (i.e. left multiplication) on the vector space $K^2$. But how does that induce an action on $K[x,y]$. For example I don't know how the image of $x$ would look like under that action, or in general how that induced action looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about what the natural representation of $\mathrm{GL}_2$ on $K^2$ is. You can think of $K[x,y]$ as the space of polynomial functions on $K^2$, where $x$ is the function returning the first coordinate and $y$ returns the second, so

$$x(a,b)=a,\:y(a,b)=b$$

Now you can define $x\cdot g(a,b)=x(g\cdot(a,b))$ for each $g\in\mathrm{GL}_2$, and similarly for $y$, to give an action of $\mathrm{GL}_2$ on $K[x,y]$. Explicitly, we have

$$\begin{pmatrix}g_{11}&g_{12}\\g_{21}&g_{22}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}g_{11}a+g_{12}b\\g_{21}a+g_{22}b\end{pmatrix}$$
so for any $(a,b)\in K^2$, we have

$$x\cdot g(a,b)=g_{11}a+g_{12}b=g_{11}x(a,b)+g_{12}y(a,b)$$

Thus $x\cdot g=g_{11}x+g_{12}y$. Similarly $y\cdot g=g_{21}x+g_{22}y$.

This turns the left action on $K^2$ into a right action on the space of functions $K[x,y]$ - if you want to stick to left actions, you will need to define $g\cdot x(a,b)=x(g^{-1}\cdot(a,b))$ instead. I hope the right choice is clear from your context.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about this. Lets say we have $2xy^2\in K[x,y]$. How would $(2xy^2)(a,b)$ now look like?

Comment: You extend the definition so that evaluation is a ring homomorphism - so $(2xy^2)(a,b)=2ab^2$. Moreover, $(2xy^2\cdot g)(a,b)$ is $2(g_{11}a+g_{12}b)(g_{21}a+g_{22}b)^2$, so $2xy^2\cdot g=2(g_{11}x+g_{12}y)(g_{21}x+g_{22}y)^2$.

Comment: To see if I understood this correctly I'll try to show that the set of invariants of $K[x,y]$ under $GL_2$ is $K$ itself: We need to find all $p\in K[x,y]$ s.t. for all $g\in GL_2$ we have that $g.p=p$. Plugging in the definition we have $p(a,b)=p(g\cdot (a,b))=p(g_{11}a+g_{12}b,g_{21}a+g_{22}b)$, where the first equality is to be shown. We see that it only holds if $p$ is constant, hence we have $K[x,y]^{GL_2}$ "is" (more precisely canonically isomorphic to) $K$ itself.

Comment: I consulted literature, too and I'm still a bit confused. Shouldn't the right group action read $(x.g)(a,b):=x((a,b)\cdot g)$?

Comment: No - you have a left action on $K^2$, so it induces a right action on $K[x,y]$; if you had a right action it would induce a left action. Either way, they can't be on the same side - in what you just wrote, you would have $(x\cdot g)\cdot h(a,b)=x\cdot g((a,b)\cdot h)=x((a,b)\cdot hg)$, which isn't $x\cdot gh(a,b)$. You either have to have the actions on opposite sides, or introduce an inverse.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand it now. In order to be able to write $g.x(a,b)$ I would have to introduce an inverse (like you did in your post) since inverting the product of matrices flips them. Nontheless writing $g.x(a,b)=(g^{-1}(a,b))$ or $x.g(a,b)=((a,b)g)$ is exactly the same. Is that right?

Comment: Not quite - you also need an inverse in the second expression, else you have the problem in my earlier comment. I'm not sure I would call them "exactly the same" either. A more precise statement is that each left action $\cdot$ induces a right action $*$ by defining $x*g=g^{-1}\cdot x$ (and vice versa) and the actions $g\cdot x(a,b)=g^{-1}(a,b)$ and $x\cdot g(a,b)=(a,b)g^{-1}$ are related in this way.

Comment: Even more precisely; a left action of $G$ is "the same" as a right action of the opposite group $G^{\mathrm{op}}$, which has the same underlying set, but the operation is defined by $g\times_{\mathrm{op}}h=h\times g$, where $\times$ is the multiplication in $G$. But $G$ and $G^{\mathrm{op}}$ are isomorphic via $g\mapsto g^{-1}$, hence the relation between left and right actions in the comment above.

Comment: I think my problem is that I don't see why the induced action is a right action. See for example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115397/why-is-the-group-action-on-the-vector-space-of-polynomials-naturally-a-left-acti). It's said that we define the action on the vectorspace of polynomials as $(g.f)(x)=f(x*g)$ or $(g.f)(x)=(g^{-1}x)$ which is a left action. Why do we have an induced action here, that is a right action?

Comment: Is it that $(g.f)(x)=(g^{-1}x)$ is the corresponding left action to $(f.g)(x)=(gx)$?

Comment: I'm fairly certain the above is correct. Since in the context of the problem left actions are required, I will use these. Let's say I want to find the image of $x$ under $G=\begin{pmatrix}g_{11}&g_{12}\\g_{21}&g_{22}\end{pmatrix}$, where the use of the left action is convention. Would I invert $G$ first to get the same result as in your OP, aka. going to $G^{op}$, or would I just work with it like it is (and make the result ugly because I would need to invert).

Comment: In what I said, the induced action was a right action because the action on $K^2$ was a left action - in what you say two comments ago, the action $*$ on the domain is a right action. What you say one comment ago is correct. In terms of what to do about your problem, you will have to use the context of the problem to work out what they want. I wouldn't be surprised if they intended the action on $K[x,y]$ described in my answer, but this isn't consistent with the action induced by the standard left action on $K^2$.

Comment: If you follow what they say completely literally, you will need to invert all the matrices, which will make the expressions messier.