# Action in $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,...,x_n]$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

> My teacher defined $*: S_n \times \mathbb{Z}[x_1,...,x_n]\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[x_1,...,x_n]$, such that: $$g*f(x_1,...,x_n)=f(x_{g(1)},...,x_{g(n)} )$$
>
> She left us an exercise to check that $\alpha*(\beta*f)=(\alpha \circ \beta)*f$.

I proved (certainly there is a mistake I cannot find) that this doesn't hold and that $\beta$ and $\alpha$ swap:

$$\alpha*(\beta*f(x_1,...,x_n))=\alpha*f(x_{\beta(1)},...,x_{\beta(n)})=\alpha*f(u_1,...,u_n)$$

Here I have named $u_j=x_{\beta(j)}$. This holds for every $j$, in particular, when $j=\alpha(i)$, thus:

$$\alpha*(\beta*f(x_1,...,x_n))=f(u_{\alpha(1)},...,u_{\alpha(n)})=f(x_{\beta\circ\alpha(1)},...,x_{\beta\circ\alpha(n)})=$$
$$(\beta\circ\alpha)*f(x_1,...,x_n)$$

Comment: First question: do you compose permutations left-to-right, or right-to-left? If $\alpha=(12)$ and $\beta=(13)$, is $\alpha\beta=(123)$, or is $\alpha\beta=(132)$?

Comment: $\alpha \beta=(1 3 2)$...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Composition of functions is usually done from right to left. Why would anyone do it otherwise with permutations?

Comment: Some authors compute permutation products left to right because (i) They are working with right actions instead of left actions; and/or (ii) It is easier to compute the product if you compose left-to-right. The two conventions are perfectly acceptable, but if you don't specify which one you are using it can lead to confusion. Also, it is perfectly sensible to use functions acting on the right: ring theorists do it all the time. If $xf$ is the result of applying the function $f$ to the element $x$, then compositing left-to-right is the "usual."

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115397/11619).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your teacher made a common error. (**Edit:** See below for a potential confusion). Probably thought that $\alpha*f(x_{\beta(1)},\cdots,x_{\beta(n)})$ would equal $f(x_{\alpha(\beta(1))},\ldots,x_{\alpha(\beta(n))})$, but that does not quite work.

Indeed, to see it doesn't work, take $n=3$, $\alpha=(12)$, and $\beta=(13)$. Then $\beta*g$ will exchange the first and third arguments of $g$, and $\alpha*h$ will exchange the first and second arguments of $h$. As we note in the comments, the right-to-left convention means that $\rho=\alpha\circ\beta=(132)$, so
$$(\alpha\circ\beta)*f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \rho*f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = f(x_{\rho(1)},x_{\rho(2)},x_{\rho(3)}) = f(x_3,x_1,x_2).$$
On the other hand,
$$\begin{align*}
\alpha*(\beta*f(x_1,x_2,x_3)) &= \alpha*f(x_3,x_2,x_1)\\
&= f(x_2,x_3,x_1),
\end{align*}$$
which would agree with composition left-to-right, but not with composition right-to-left.

For instance, if $f(x,y,z) = xy^2z^3$, then $(13)*f(x,y,z) = f(z,y,x)$, and $(12)*f(z,y,x) = f(y,z,x)$, so $(12)\circ(13)*f(x,y,z) = yz^2x^3$. But $(132)*f(x,y,z) = f(z,x,y) = zx^2y^3\neq yz^2x^3 = f(y,x,z)=(123)*f(x,y,z)$.

To define a left action by acting on the indices, you need the formula
$$\alpha*f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = f(x_{\alpha^{-1}(1)},\ldots,x_{\alpha^{-1}(n)}).$$

---

Okay, there is some confusion here and in the comments, because there are actually *two* ways of interpreting this action.

Because of how it is written, I am interpreting the action as follows:

> Start with the tuple $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. Then use $\sigma\in S_n$ to shuffle the entries tuple by shuffling the positions; then feed the result into $f$.

Thus, my calculations above: $(13)$ acts on the tuple $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ by putting what was in the $\sigma(1)=3$rd entry into the first position, leaving the second position in place, and putting what was in the $\sigma(3)=1$st entry into the third position; that is, exchanging entries in positions $1$ and $3$, giving $(x_3,x_2,x_1)$. Similarly, $(12)$ acts on a $3$-tuple by exchanging entries in the first and second position, so when applied to $(x_3,x_2,x_1)$ we get $(x_2,x_3,x_1)$.

And $(12)(13) = (132)$ acts by putting the $\sigma(1)=3$rd entry in the first position, the $\sigma(2)=1$st entry in the second position, and the $\sigma(3)=2$nd entry in the third position. So applying it to $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ we get $(x_3,x_1,x_2)$. That is, $(132)$ acting on $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ does not yield the same result as first letting $(13)$ act on it, and then letting $(12)$ act on the result.

So if we "feed" the result of letting $(13)$ act on $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and then letting $(12)$ act on the resulting $(x_3,x_2,x_1)$ to get $(x_2,x_3,x_1)$, into polynomial $f$, we will get $f(x_2,x_3,x_1)$. Whereas if we "feed" the result of letting $(132)$ act on $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ into $f$, we will get $f(x_3,x_1,x_2)$, which is not necessarily the same end result.

(I interpret it this way because that is the standard way to let a permutation act in, say, a wreath product, which is where I usually encounter this type of "index shuffling".)

Taking $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_1x_2^2x_3^3$, the result of doing $(12)*\Bigl( (13)*f\Bigr)$ is
$$f(x_2,x_3,x_1) = x_2x_3^2x_1^3$$
whereas doing $(132)*f$ will give
$$f(x_3,x_1,x_2) = x_3x_1^2x_2^3.$$

This interpretation actually defines a *right* action; if we want to turn it into a left action, we use the standard correspondence, which is to let $g$ act on the left like $g^{-1}$ acts on the right, hence $\sigma*f$ being $f$ applied to $(x_{\sigma^{-1}(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma^{-1}(n)})$.

However, one may also interpret it as follows:

> First apply $f$ to $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$; then replace $x_i$ with $x_{\sigma(i)}$ in the resulting expression.

For a single permutation, the two actions yield the same answer: if
$$f(x_1, \ldots,x_n) = \sum \alpha_{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)}x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_n^{a_n}$$
where $\alpha_{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)}=0$ for almost all tuples, then shuffling the output will give
$$\sum \alpha_{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)}x_{\sigma(1)}^{a_1}\cdots x_{\sigma(n)}^{a_n}$$
which is also what we get if we evaluate $f(x_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma(n)})$, because that is
$$\sum \alpha_{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)}x_{\sigma(1)}^{a_1}\cdots x_{\sigma(n)}^{a_n}.$$

But *this* behaves differently under composition: looking again at $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_1x_2^2x_3^3$, if we first apply the permutation $\sigma(13)$ to this output, we get
$$x_{\sigma(1)}x_{\sigma(2)}^2 x_{\sigma(3)}^3 = x_3x_2^2x_1^3 = x_1^3x_2^2x_3.$$
If we *then* apply the permutation $\tau=(12)$ to *this* monomial, we get
$$x_{\tau(1)}^3 x_{\tau(2)}^2 x_{\tau(3)} = x_2^3 x_1^2 x_3 = x_1^2x_2^3x_3 = f(x_3,x_1,x_2).$$
And this is the same as applying $\rho=\tau\sigma=(12)(13) = (132)$ to $x_1x_2^2x_3^3$:
$$x_{\rho(1)} x_{\rho(2)}^2 x_{\rho(3)}^3 = x_3x_1^2x_2^3 = x_1^2x_2^3x_3.$$

This *does* define a left action.

Wherein lies the potential confusion. Your calculations were concordant with my first interpretation. The one in the comments below by Mor A are working with the second plausible reading.

If we think of $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ as functions with domain tuples, the first interpretation is more sensible. If we think of them as the polynomial expressions, the second is more sensible. I am used to actions on tuples, so I did the first interpretation.

Comment: Question regarding your calculation in the example: From what I can tell for $f(x,y,z)=xy^2z^3$, I'll denote $h(x,y,z)=(1 3) * f(x,y,z)=f(z,y,x)=zy^2x^3$, and then $(1 2)*((1 3)* f(x,y,z)) = (1 2) * h(x, y, z)= h(y,x,z)=zx^2y^3$ which is also what your calculated as $((1 2)\circ (1 3))* f(x,y,z)$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MorA. You are first applying the polynomial and then shuffling the variables. Because of how it is written, I am interpreting it as shuffling the input "streams" before applying the function, and then applying the function. For a single application there is no difference, but you get different answers in a composition. I'll write it up carefully later. Basically, one is a left action and the other is a right action.

Comment: @MorA. See the edit, explanation below the horizontal line.